# Windows security event search on Logon Type

Tags: xml, regex, events, vbscript

I need to write code that will search for Windows security events meeting certain criteria and return the events. I have a constraint that I need to use VBscript for this, I cannot use PowerShell. The problem is that one of the fields that needs to be searchable is "Logon Type" (in the messages field). This is an example of Logon Type in a security event:

[image: Example]

I have looked all over the internet for a way to do this and the only thing I can come up with is to use regex and the `InStr` function to search within the `Messages` field, but that method would be quite complicated and cumbersome with the other search values being a factor as well. As an FYI, the other value I need to search for is time.

Or, is there a way to export all the security events from a machine to XML? I have not found a way to do that with VBscript.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can best filter messages based on logon type with VBscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how checking the message field for a specific logon type would be that complicated. Something like this should suffice:

```vbs
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "LogonType:\s+7"

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile='Security' AND EventCode=4624"
For Each evt In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  If re.Test(evt.Message) Then
    'do stuff
  End If
Next
```

Comment: It works! I just changed `If re.Test(msg) Then` to `If re.Test(evt.Message) Then` (keeping with the WMI query).

Comment: @CircuitB0T: Ah, sorry. That was a copy/paste error on my part. Fixed.